# Casperjs script runs on OSX but not Windows

Tags: ssl, phantomjs, casperjs

Phantomjs version - 1.9.7
Casperjs version - 1.1.0-beta3

This is the code

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',

});

casper.start('https://www.gmail.com', function() {
    casper.wait(3000, function()  {
        this.capture('gmail.png');
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

The logs on Windows show

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true login.js
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.gmail.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.gmail.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://www.gmail.com/
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 349ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3: done in 371ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 3000ms.
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/username/Desktop/gmail.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/username/Desktop/gmail.png
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 3408ms
```

On OSX it shows the following

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.gmail.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.gmail.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://mail.google.com/mail/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/CheckConnection?pmpo=https://accounts.google.com&v=-320444755&timestamp=1420230909413, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1 (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 1398ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3 https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1 (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3: done in 1418ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 3000ms.
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to /Users/username/code/casperjs/gmail.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to /Users/username/code/casperjs/gmail.png
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 4511ms
```

The code is the same on both platforms, I have tried various combinations of --ignore-ssl-errors etc with no luck. Any suggestions?

Based on Artjom B.'s suggestions, I have updated the code like this -

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1'
    }
});

casper.on('resource.error', function(resource) {
    this.echo('Error: ' +msg, 'ERROR'); });

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
    console.log('Response (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
};

casper.on("remote.message", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.start('https://www.gmail.com', function() {
    casper.wait(3000, function()  {
        this.capture('gmail.png');
    });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

This gives the same result -

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true pt-login.js
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.gmail.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.gmail.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://www.gmail.com/
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 338ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3: done in 361ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 3000ms.
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/username/Desktop/gmail.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/username/Desktop/gmail.png
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 3462ms
```

Comment: Verbose and debug do not provide all information. Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Have you tried setting the user agent using: `casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1');` before `start`?

Comment: yes, edited the question with the results. No change

Comment: I don't have a problem on windows with PhantomJS 1.9.8. I can't test 1.9.7, but it should work with the ssl-protocol option. By the way, `page.onResourceTimeout` is wrong, it has to be `casper.page.onResourceTimeout`, but only after `start`, so you would call empty start, register to `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` inside of a `then` and then use `thenOpen` to open gmail. You can then remove the first two lines.

Comment: maybe related : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/casperjs/W0BsRe_i6aI/z3z1Gw4r73QJ